# How can I display a set amount of ticks on the Y Axis?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, axis-labels

I have a chart where I already know the set amount of ticks I'll need. There's 3 with a grouped bar type chart. I'm scratching my head over how to force it. Right now it's showing 0 to whatever number ends up in my data set and auto scales as required.

By default it's assumed I'm using numbers to scale but in this scenario it's a Positive, neutral, negative (those labels literally) on Y-Axis that are the data points related to a specific date on X axis (with 2 grouped bars labeled AM/PM).

The Chart.js documentation doesn't seem to explain how to tweak when working outside of numbers on the ticks configurations and I'm not sure how to shoehorn this in. Any ideas? Below is the code for as far as I've gotten.

The screenshot example I basically simulated the 3 data points by choosing 4,8 and 12. I would like those labels to be (negative,positive,neutral) and make all other ticks disappear.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Date/MoonCenter', 'Date/MoonCenter', 'Date/MoonCenter'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1', backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
stack: 'Stack 0',
            data: [4, 12, 4, 8, 12, 4]
        },{
            label: 'Dataset 1', backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
stack: 'Stack 1',
            data: [8, 8, 12, 4, 4, 12]          
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

[image: Chart as it looks currently]

Comment: Please show what code you currently have, include an example of the current output (e.g. a screenshot), and if possible, provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I've updated the post with the code as it runs currently and a screenshot (link because I don't have image rights yet) of the chart so far. I also updated the description before the code so you get the "gist" of what i'm going for

Answer (score 3):

you just need add the callback in the ticks,

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src='Chart.js'></script>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Date/MoonCenter', 'Date/MoonCenter', 'Date/MoonCenter'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1', backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                data: [4, 12, 4, 8, 12, 4]
            }, {
                label: 'Dataset 1', backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                stack: 'Stack 1',
                data: [8, 8, 12, 4, 4, 12]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            callback: function (label, index, labels) {
                                switch (label) {
                                    case 4:
                                        return 'negative';
                                    case 8:
                                        return 'positive';
                                    case 12:
                                        return 'neutral';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the same switch case to force a maximum? It seems like if I don't have a case 12 for example, then it'll cut the chart short without showing that tick (neutral in this example). I won't always have all 3 at once for a date range but it might be jarring to have one third of the chart's Y-Axis cut out

Comment: Any follow ups to this? This is only partially a solution. It doesn't address that if my data range does not have the top most value, it will truncate it to the two bottom ones. I want to have the 3 tickets display at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to saul's answer:
Just add max-settings to the y-axis.

```
ticks: {
  max: 12
}
```

You also have to do callbacks for the tooltip if you want to display "positive", "negative" and "neutral" instead of 4, 8 and 12.